# SQLSTATE[08P01]: <>: 7 ERROR: el mensaje de enlace (bind) entrega 1 parámetros, pero la sentencia preparada «pdo_stmt_00000003» requiere 0 (SQL:)

Tags: laravel

tengo este error que no se solucionar, quiero hacer una consulta a la base de datos que sea dinámica según el nombre que le pase, pero no para de salirme este mensaje:

> SQLSTATE[08P01]: <>: 7 ERROR:  el mensaje de enlace (bind) entrega 1 parámetros, pero la sentencia preparada «pdo_stmt_00000003» requiere 0 (SQL:)

¿La verdad que me estoy pediendo con la manera de hacer consultas de Laravel, por que no podria ser algo mas intuitivo y permitir que la variable se lea desde donde se lo estoy indicando?

este es el codigo:

```
public function store(Request $request){
       return = DB::select('select * from productor where productor.nombre = ?' 
       [$request-> nombre]);
    }
```

tambien aplica para esta consulta, de hecho esta es la importante, pero como tiene tanto contenido pensé en usar una mas simple que tenia con el mismo error

```
public function store(Request $request){
       return = DB::select(`select proveedor.id
                         from proveedor
                        where proveedor.id_proveedor in (
                              select proveedor.id_proveedor
                                from proveedor, 
                                     condicion_envio as envio, 
                                     pais
                               where envio.id_proveedor = proveedor.id_proveedor
                                     and pais.id_pais = envio.id_pais 
                                     and LOWER(pais.nombre) = ?
                               )`,
                    [$request-> nombre]);
    }
```

Entiendo que hay otras formas de hacerlo con laravel, ya es algo que he investigado, pero tengo una base de datos con 46 tablas a las que le tendria que agregar un modelo y tengo que hacer consultas a múltiples tabla y es algo que no he encontrado fácilmente por internet.

En conclusion Solo necesito una forma en la que la consulta así como la hice  pueda cambiarme el valor de "?" por el valor de la variable $request -> nombre y que haga la consulta correctamente evitando el error 500

Comment: necesito usar consultas mas complejas a varias tablas al mismo tiempo, tengo 46 tablas montadas en una base de datos y esta fue la forma mas sencilla que encontré para comunicarme y hacer consultas

Comment: erro al copiar y arreglado. Es de copiado por que ya he usado el mismo comando DB::select() pero sin querer agregarle variables  y ahí si me retorna la lista de datos que quiero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#running-queries)

La forma de proceder para ejecutar consultas con sintaxis pura de SQL se hace así:

```
DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

Haciendo uso del facade `DB` y del método `select`

Entonces tu consulta debe ser así

```
DB::select('select * from productor where productor.nombre = ?',[ $request-> nombre]);
```

Aunque como te dije esto sería una consulta muy fácil y más limpia de hacer con los métodos del query builder en todo caso y se vería así:

```
Modelo::select('*')->whereNombre($request->nombre)->first();
```